# Pass Array via Query String to HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, arrays, query-string, httphandler

I've looked all over, and I can't find a solution for this.  Correction: I find solutions, but they (I can't make them) work.

I'm passing an array to an HttpHandler via the query string.  I've read that you read it this way:

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    Dim request As HttpRequest = context.Request

    For u = 0 To request.QueryString("arrayIneed").Count - 1
        selectPONumber.Add(request.QueryString("arrayIneed")(u))
    Next
```

Doing this, regardless of whether the query string format is arrayIneed=data1,data2... or arrayIneed=[data1,data2...], chops everything after = into single values.

Please help.  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.QueryString("arrayIneed")
```

will just pull a string out
if you need it as an array then you will need to split it into one

```
 dim arr = Request.QueryString("arrayINeed").Split(",")
 For Each s In arr
    selectPoNumber.Add(s)
 Next
```

worth noting that if your po number array is one of integers, you will have to convert s into an int